# why is there no mysql connector cpp package in msys2?

Tags: msys2

There is no mysql connector cpp package in msys2 like `mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient` which is for mariadb.

I am trying to connect to mysql db from c++, I have installed cpp via msys2.

Comment: The way your phrased your question invites opinionated answers.  You could try submitting a MySQL package to the MSYS2 maintainers and see what happens, or you could just try the MariaDB package and see if it works, since MariaDB and MySQL are pretty similar.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Sorry I will edit my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is there no mysql connector cpp package in msys2?

> There is no mysql connector cpp package in msys2 like [`mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient`](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient) which is for mariadb.

You answered your own question: the MariaDB client is binary-compatible with MySQL, so *ostensibly* you can use `mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient` with a MySQL server:

[https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#:~:text=MariaDB's%20client%20protocol%20is%20binary,Perl%2C%20Python%2C%20Java%2C%20](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#:%7E:text=MariaDB%27s%20client%20protocol%20is%20binary,Perl%2C%20Python%2C%20Java%2C%20).

> MariaDB's client protocol **is binary compatible with MySQL's client protocol**.
>
> - **All client APIs and structs are identical**.
> - All ports and sockets are generally the same.
> - All MySQL connectors (PHP, Perl, Python, Java, .NET, MyODBC, Ruby, MySQL C connector etc) work unchanged with MariaDB.

Comment: I have used mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libmariadbclient package as I had ucrt installation of cpp in msys2.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to compile mysql program with the help of `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libmariadbclient` in my msys2.

Below is the sample program I compiled and ran on windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "", "user", 0, NULL, 0);
    if (conn)
    {
        cout << " Connection to database successful:" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Connection unsuccessful" << endl;
    }
    // Execute a simple query
    if (mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM user")) {
        std::cerr << "Error querying database: " << mysql_error(conn) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the result
    res = mysql_store_result(conn);

    // Get column information
    MYSQL_FIELD *field;
    while ((field = mysql_fetch_field(res))) {
        std::cout << field->name << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Print the results
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mysql_num_fields(res); i++) {
            if (row[i] != NULL) {
                std::cout << row[i] << "\t";
            } else {
                std::cout << "NULL\t";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // Clean up
    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(conn);
    return 0;
}
```

The command to compile above program is `g++ mysql.cpp -o mysql -lmariadb`.
mysql.cpp is the name of the program file.